# What are the possible designs to solve this concurrency problem?

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns, c#-4.0, concurrency

Greetings Overflowers,

Users execute transactions, transactions execute queries, queries execute index operations.
I've limited number of threads and I want to give them, in order of priority, to users then transactions then queries then index operations.
Note that dependencies might exist between executions.
If there are available threads I want more granular executions to utilize them.
What are the possible designs to model such dynamics ?
Any good recent books on concurrency design patterns ?

PS: I'm using c#.net 4

Regards

Comment: So, while looking for a book on concurrency, you've decided that you know better than windows and your dbms? This sounds like a bad idea from the outset. If you need to rewrite the threading model for your OS and database, then perhaps that OS and database aren't suitable for your project.

Comment: @Winston: assumptions... I'm actually coding a dbms for some special needs, that's why I need to do the concurrency :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you should take a look into [Patterns for Parallel Programming: Understanding and Applying Parallel Patterns with the .NET Framework 4](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=86b3d32b-ad26-4bb8-a3ae-c1637026c3ee&displaylang=en).